# FOR stopping before it should

Tags: javascript, excel

I have this code that get information inside a .xls file.
This is the end of the code as i think here I have a limit.
Its showing until the 50th line.

If I have more it is not working.
I dont know if you can help me just looking inside this code:

```js
for (var cal = 0; cal < excelRows.length; cal++) {
  var lixo = excelRows[cal].CaseDate
  var lixo2 = excelRows[cal].Checkin

  lixoDate = new Date(lixo)
  var lixoc = Math.round(lixoDate / offset)

  lixo2Date = new Date(lixo2)
  var lixo2c = Math.round(lixo2Date / offset)

  var dif = lixo2c - lixoc

  if (dif >= 30) {
    var dataat = new Date(document.getElementById("today").value)
    var final = Math.abs(lixoDate - dataat.getTime())
    var final2 = Math.round(final / offset)
    dif = dif - 30 - final2
    divteste.innerHTML += ` ${dif}<br>`

  } else if (dif >= 15 && dif <= 30) {
    var dataat = new Date(document.getElementById("today").value)
    var final = Math.abs(lixoDate - dataat.getTime())
    var final2 = Math.round(final / offset)
    dif = dif - 15 - final2
    divteste.innerHTML += ` ${dif}<br>`

  } else if (dif >= 3 && dif <= 14) {
    var dataat = new Date(document.getElementById("today").value)
    var final = Math.abs(lixoDate - dataat.getTime())
    var final2 = Math.round(final / offset)
    dif = dif - 3 - final2
    divteste.innerHTML += ` ${dif}<br>`
  } else if (dif <= 2) {
    divteste.innetHTML += '0'
  }
}
}
```

Comment: you should post a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), there's not entough here to give you answer, but i suspect there are really only 50 elemetns in the `excelRows` array.

Comment: if possible, would be good to have a [mcve] or at least some informations about: Any console errors? What does it shows if you `console.log(excelRows.length)` ?

Comment: You can do the `console.log` before and after the loop to see if you have more than 50 rows loaded as well as seeing if somehow you are truncating it in the loop. It doesn't look like you are doing anything to modify the `excelRows`, but it's always good to double check unintended behaviors.

Comment: Check if there is any issue in the 51st line.